# How do I build jar file in Android studio using gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

I want to build dependency.
I have `gcm-src.jar` file.and i want to show `compile files('libs/gcm-src.jar')` in app build.gradle.

Comment: Refer this link and let me know,
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/7378951

Comment: thanks @ Aanchi Dev , its work perfectly..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your gradle file

```
// For making jar
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/libs/nameOfYourJar.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'nameOfYourJar.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```